# ROS fuerte - check subscriber

Tags: ros, subscribe, nodehandle

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I want to check if a subscriber has subscribe properly to a topic. I read in documentation (http://docs.ros.org/api/roscpp/html/classros_1_1NodeHandle.html#aad44a59900a86f6d24f175b28e20c8a3) that this is made checking nodehandle but compiler sais that cant convert nodehandle to bool.

```
    ros::NodeHandle n;
    /* ... */
    intruder_sub[i]=n.subscribe(topicname.c_str(), 0,Intruder_StateCallBack);
    if(n){
        cout << "cant subscribe to " << topicname << endl;
        assert(false);
    }
```

What I'm doing wrong?
Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/205272/ros-fuerte---check-subscriber/) by [Bardo91](https://answers.ros.org/users/12326/bardo91/) on ROS Answers with karma: 30 on 2015-03-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Well, thats a bit misleading in the documentation you linked.

ros::NodeHandle cannot be converted to bool, ros::Subscriber can and the conversion returns true, i. e. 1, if the subscriber is valid:

http://docs.ros.org/api/roscpp/html/classros_1_1Subscriber.html#a04f246a951fd00f27ca439e46819d0c2
http://docs.ros.org/api/roscpp/html/subscriber_8h_source.html#l00071

In your case it'd be:

```
ros::NodeHandle n;
/* ... */
intruder_sub[i]=n.subscribe(topicname.c_str(), 0,Intruder_StateCallBack);
if( intruder_sub[i] ){
    cout << "cant subscribe to " << topicname << endl;
    assert(false);
}
```

In the docu you linked
(http://docs.ros.org/api/roscpp/html/classros_1_1NodeHandle.html#aad44a59900a86f6d24f175b28e20c8a3)
it'd be clearer to understand if it were:

```
if (sub)
{
...
}
```

Maybe someone should open a ticket to update that....

---

Originally posted by [Wolf](https://answers.ros.org/users/4478/wolf/) with karma: 7555 on 2015-03-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Bardo91](https://answers.ros.org/users/12326/bardo91/) on 2015-03-18**:
That's it. Thank you very much. I put the ticket.